# Problemas con Jaxb2Marshaller al migrar de javax a jakarta

Tags: java, wsdl, xsd

Estoy migrando un proyecto de Springboot 2 a 3 con Java 17. Tengo un marshaller que usa Jaxb2Marshaller y me convierte xsd y wsdl a clases compiladas usando javax cuando quiero que las convierta en clases con jakarta. He incluído las librerías de jakarta.xml.bind-api, jakarta.xml.ws-api y jakarta.validation-api. El método java en concreto es:

```
    @Bean("BookingMarshaller")
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.sabre.asx.crossing");
    marshaller.setContextPaths();
    return marshaller;
}
```

Y la configuración que he puesto es:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

¿A qué podría deberse que al tratar los xsd y wsdl no use jakarta? Gracias de antemano